# insertar varias galerías lightbox en la misma pagina

Tags: javascript, html5, css, css3

estoy realizando una pagina web en la cual debo poner varias galerías(lightbox) en la mismas pagina para ver diferentes vehículos con sus fotos, lo que sucede es que al dar clic en la foto de uno de los vehículos se despliega solo la primer galería independientemente de que galería quiera ver adjunto el código

```js
<script>
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById('myModal').style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
    slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
</script>
```

```css
.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

img.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19)
}
```

```html
<!-- gallery -->
 <div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
   <h3><span></span>Remates</h3>
   <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
 <div  class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/ford/1.jpg" width="250" height="200" rel="galeria1" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
 
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/ford/1.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/ford/20170210_092722.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/ford/20170210_092739.jpg" rel="galeria1"  style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/ford/20170210_092803.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/ford/1.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/ford/20170210_092722.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/ford/20170210_092739.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/ford/20170210_092803.jpg" rel="galeria1" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul>

    <li>
    Codigo:
    </li>
    <li>
    Departamento:
    </li>
    <li>
    Municipio: 
    </li>
    <li>
    Valor Venta:
    </li>
    <li>
    M2:
    </li>
                                <li>
    Caracteristicas: 
    </li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    
    
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


    
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <script src="js/jzBox.js"></script>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //gallery -->
<!-- gallery2 -->
 <div class="gallery">
  <div class="container">
   <h3><span></span>Remates</h3>
   <br>
    <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="col-md-4">
 <div  class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="images/sandero/20170203_084934.jpg" width="250" height="200"  rel="galeria2" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow">
  </div>
 
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/sandero/20170203_084934.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/sandero/20170203_085320.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/sandero/20170203_085345.jpg" rel="galeria2"  style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
        <img src="images/sandero/20170203_085424.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/sandero/20170203_084934.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/sandero/20170203_085320.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/sandero/20170203_085345.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="">
    </div>

    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo" src="images/sandero/20170203_085424.jpg" rel="galeria2" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul>

    <li>
    Codigo:
    </li>
    <li>
    Departamento:
    </li>
    <li>
    Municipio: 
    </li>
    <li>
    Valor Venta:
    </li>
    <li>
    M2:
    </li>
                                <li>
    Caracteristicas: 
    </li>
    
   </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
   <ul>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    <li>
     Informacion
    </li>
    
    
   </ul>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>


    
     </div>
    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <script src="js/jzBox.js"></script>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
<!-- //gallery2 -->
```

Comment: yo uso una libreria lightbox muy fácil de usar, no tiene ese problema que mencionas

Answer (score 0):

Entre otras cosas, no puedes repetir en más de una ocasión el mismo id en una misma página (id="myModal", id="caption"..), y teniendo esto en cuenta, muy probablemente, al lightbox le estas pasando ese id y ejecuta el script en el primero que encuentra. Debes poner id diferentes a cada lightbox y configurar el lightbox para cada una de las galerías.